# Spring Boot JPA Repository Filter + Pagination + Query By Example (QBE)

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, query-by-example, jparepository

I am working on a Spring Boot Application using Java GraphQL.  I have a scenario where I want to return only the Users for a specific Account ID, but I also want to be able to filter that list down even further by allowing the front-end application to send additional filter parameters/values, and also need the results to be paginated.

The `QueryByExampleExecutor<T>` has this method already:

```java
    <S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
```

But ultimately what I would like to be able to do would be to have something like:

```java
    <S extends T> Page<S> findAllByAccountsId(long accountId, Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
```

Is this even possible or do I need to write a custom repository method to support this?  And if you have to write a custom method, how do you still handle Pagination and QBE manually?

**BaseEntity.java**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
//----------------------------------------
// Member Variables
//----------------------------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

//----------------------------------------
// Getter Methods
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Returns the ID of the entity
     *
     * @return the entity ID
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Date that the entity was created at
     *
     * @return the entity's creation date
     */
    public OffsetDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return this.createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Date that the entity was updated last
     *
     * @return the entity's date it was last updated
     */
    public OffsetDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return this.updatedAt;
    }

//----------------------------------------
// Lifecycle Methods
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * The lifecycle hook to run on the entity before it is persisted to the database for the first time
     */
    @PrePersist
    public void onBaseModelSave() {
        var now = OffsetDateTime.now();

        this.createdAt = now;
        this.updatedAt = now;
    }

    /**
     * The lifecycle hook to run on the entity before it is updated
     */
    @PreUpdate
    public void onBaseModelUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
//----------------------------------------
// Member Variables
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Associations
     */

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Account> accounts;

    ...
}
```

**Accounts.java**

```java
@Entity
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
//----------------------------------------
// Member Variables
//----------------------------------------

    /**
     * Single Values
     */

    private String name;
    private String timezone;
    private boolean isActive;

    /**
     * Multiple Associations
     */

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "account_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<User> users;

   ...
}
```

AccountRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}
```

UserRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

I feel like this isn't an abnormal use case, but I am struggling for some reason to wrap my head around the correct solution.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Page<User> findAllByAccountsId(long accountId, Example<User> userExample, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Startup error:

```
surgio-api     | [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
surgio-api     | [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [ERROR] /app/src/main/java/io/surgio/api/services/UserServiceImpl.java:[291,35] method findAllByAccountsId in interface io.surgio.api.repositories.interfaces.UserRepository cannot be applied to given types;
surgio-api     |   required: long,org.springframework.data.domain.Example<io.surgio.api.entities.User>,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
surgio-api     |   found:    long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
surgio-api     |   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
surgio-api     | [INFO] 1 error
surgio-api     | [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
surgio-api     | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [INFO] Total time:  4.249 s
surgio-api     | [INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-14T17:13:27Z
surgio-api     | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
surgio-api     | [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Compilation failure
surgio-api     | [ERROR] /app/src/main/java/io/surgio/api/services/UserServiceImpl.java:[291,35] method findAllByAccountsId in interface io.surgio.api.repositories.interfaces.UserRepository cannot be applied to given types;
surgio-api     | [ERROR]   required: long,org.springframework.data.domain.Example<io.surgio.api.entities.User>,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
surgio-api     | [ERROR]   found:    long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
surgio-api     | [ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
surgio-api     | [ERROR]
surgio-api     | [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
surgio-api     | [ERROR]
surgio-api     | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
surgio-api     | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
surgio-api     | [ERROR]
surgio-api     | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
surgio-api     | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
mailhog        | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
```